# iBooks Pop-up Footnote Font

Tags: fonts, ibooks, footnotes

How can I control the font iBooks uses to display pop-up footnotes?

In the CSS I have set the body font to Helvetica with DejaVuSans providing some glyphs not in Helvetica. When the footnotes display at the end of the chapter as a list, they use Helvetica. When the footnotes appear in the pop-up, they are using some serif font.

For example, in the text I have:

```
<a epub:type="noteref" class="noteref" href="#fn1" id="fnref1">1</a>
```

At the end I have a section for footnotes:

```
<section epub:type="footnotes" id="ch002footnotes">
<hr />
<ol>
<li epub:type="footnote" id="fn1">Thomas Kuhn, <cite>The Structure of Scientific Revolutions</cite>, 51.<a href="#fnref1">&#160;&#8617;</a></li>
…
</ol>
</section>
```

When I touch the footnote reference, the note pops up as expected but uses a serif font rather than Helvetica.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't appear to work on the iBooks popups, but I did manage to control font size with  (where x equals a number ranging from 1 to 7) tag. Italics appears to work the same way, so maybe worth experimenting...

Comment: (sorry, first attempt removed markup) CSS doesn't appear to work on the iBooks popups, but HTML tags appear to. I can control font size with the font size tag.

Comment: Yup, iBooks popups seem to ignore CSS, but for example you can make something italic using `<i>text</i>`.